# Ubuntu 19.10 Upgrade - VMware Not Working

Tags: upgrade, vmware

I upgraded to the latest version of Ubuntu (19.10) and now VMware Player won't work -- 'Unable to start services' -- when running the VMware Kernel Module Updater.  So, I looked at the log file (see below) and saw the very last line '2020-02-05T14:29:19.554-08:00| host-6114| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.'.  I think this is the issue (only one?) but searching online hasn't helped at all. I tried uninstalling VMware and re-installing, but that didn't work. Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks,
Ryan

```
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=6114 version=15.1.0 build=build-13591040 option=Release
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: Host is Linux 5.3.0-29-generic Ubuntu 19.10
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/tacchino/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/tacchino/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.794-08:00| host-6114| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/tacchino/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.827-08:00| host-6114| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-6114.log
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: Setting header path for 5.3.0-29-generic to "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include".
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2020-02-05T14:29:16.846-08:00| host-6114| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-9 for preprocess check
2020-02-05T14:29:16.852-08:00| host-6114| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:16.852-08:00| host-6114| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.3.0-29-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2020-02-05T14:29:16.984-08:00| host-6114| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/Module.symvers
2020-02-05T14:29:16.984-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Read 23594 symbol versions
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.001-08:00| host-6114| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.004-08:00| host-6114| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.004-08:00| host-6114| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.007-08:00| host-6114| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.007-08:00| host-6114| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.009-08:00| host-6114| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.009-08:00| host-6114| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.014-08:00| host-6114| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.031-08:00| host-6114| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2020-02-05T14:29:17.042-08:00| host-6114| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.042-08:00| host-6114| I125: Setting header path for 5.3.0-29-generic to "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.042-08:00| host-6114| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.042-08:00| host-6114| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2020-02-05T14:29:17.042-08:00| host-6114| I125: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.042-08:00| host-6114| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-9 for preprocess check
2020-02-05T14:29:17.049-08:00| host-6114| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.049-08:00| host-6114| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.3.0-29-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2020-02-05T14:29:17.187-08:00| host-6114| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/Module.symvers
2020-02-05T14:29:17.187-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.203-08:00| host-6114| I125: Read 23594 symbol versions
2020-02-05T14:29:17.205-08:00| host-6114| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include
2020-02-05T14:29:17.205-08:00| host-6114| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include
2020-02-05T14:29:17.205-08:00| host-6114| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.205-08:00| host-6114| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2020-02-05T14:29:17.205-08:00| host-6114| I125: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.205-08:00| host-6114| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-9 for preprocess check
2020-02-05T14:29:17.212-08:00| host-6114| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.212-08:00| host-6114| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.3.0-29-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2020-02-05T14:29:17.213-08:00| host-6114| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2020-02-05T14:29:17.215-08:00| host-6114| I125: Got gcc version "9".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.215-08:00| host-6114| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.217-08:00| host-6114| I125: Got gcc version "9".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.218-08:00| host-6114| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.220-08:00| host-6114| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.220-08:00| host-6114| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.220-08:00| host-6114| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.221-08:00| host-6114| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.221-08:00| host-6114| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2020-02-05T14:29:17.221-08:00| host-6114| I125: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.221-08:00| host-6114| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-9 for preprocess check
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.3.0-29-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.227-08:00| host-6114| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-9 for preprocess check
2020-02-05T14:29:17.234-08:00| host-6114| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.234-08:00| host-6114| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.3.0-29-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2020-02-05T14:29:17.234-08:00| host-6114| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.238-08:00| host-6114| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.238-08:00| host-6114| I125: Setting header path for 5.3.0-29-generic to "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.238-08:00| host-6114| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for kernel release "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.238-08:00| host-6114| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2020-02-05T14:29:17.238-08:00| host-6114| I125: /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.238-08:00| host-6114| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-9 for preprocess check
2020-02-05T14:29:17.243-08:00| host-6114| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "5.3.0-29-generic".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.243-08:00| host-6114| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include" for the kernel "5.3.0-29-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2020-02-05T14:29:17.375-08:00| host-6114| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/Module.symvers
2020-02-05T14:29:17.375-08:00| host-6114| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2020-02-05T14:29:17.391-08:00| host-6114| I125: Read 23594 symbol versions
2020-02-05T14:29:17.391-08:00| host-6114| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2020-02-05T14:29:17.395-08:00| host-6114| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2020-02-05T14:29:18.125-08:00| host-6114| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2020-02-05T14:29:18.125-08:00| host-6114| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2020-02-05T14:29:18.135-08:00| host-6114| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2020-02-05T14:29:18.135-08:00| host-6114| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j16 -C /tmp/modconfig-hPYqox/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2020-02-05T14:29:19.554-08:00| host-6114| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: I've just posted an answer, let us know if it works for you. Also, you can create a script by copying the highlighted part in a text editor, and save it as "vmware-patch.sh" (or with any other filename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script based on [mkucebek's GitHub repo](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules) for VMware host modules patches, make it executable, and run it each time it's needed. Usually when you install a new kernel. I have modified it for the version you've installed, VMware Player 15.1.0:

```
#!/bin/bash 
VMWARE_VERSION=player-15.1.0
TMP_FOLDER=/tmp/patch-vmware
rm -fdr $TMP_FOLDER
mkdir -p $TMP_FOLDER
cd $TMP_FOLDER
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd $TMP_FOLDER/vmware-host-modules
git checkout $VMWARE_VERSION
git fetch
make
sudo make install
sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

The same workaround has also been accepted as [the solution in VMware communities](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/609330).

Comment: Right on!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same problem here. Simply tried to open my VMWare Workstation, it asked for a require rebuild:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM41n.png)
Some seconds after, The Monitor and Network device failed, I've checked the logs and got similar as Ryan.

Ubuntu 18.04 & kernel 5.3.0-28-generic here.

The github above works as well with VMWare Workstation? *-- Ran it using Workstation*

**EDIT:** the script above was returning the same error than I was having before so I finally get everything back and running just by upgrading VMWare Workstation.

Download latest VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.0-14665864.x86_64.bundle then:

```
export LC_ALL=C (for 'buffer too small error')
sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.0-14665864.x86_64.bundle
```

Worked like a charm, cheers.

Comment: yes, modified this line `VMWARE_VERSION=player-15.1.0` in the script. For example, `VMWARE_VERSION=workstation-15.1.0`, keeping everything else as it is. Also, enter the correct version of the VMware Workstation too... the version you have installed.